# Azure: How to delete a private link service that has a private endpoint connected to it?

Tags: azure, endpoint

When I try to delete a Private Link Service resource in Azure, it shows the error "cannot be deleted since it has 1 private endpoint connections. Please delete all private endpoint connections before deleting the private link service."

The private endpoint is controlled by a different organization within my company and it is very hard to get them to respond to requests like this.

Is there any way to get past this error message and delete the Private Link Service even if it has a connected Private Endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

If you run this PowerShell command, does it list the endpoints? You can run if from the portal using the Cloud Shell.

```
Get-AzPrivateEndpoint -ResourceGroupName $rgName -ExpandResource networkinterfaces
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the private endpoint if you have access to PLS. This can be done from [portal](https://portal.azure.com) easily.

1. Open PLS
2. Settings > Private endpoint connections
3. Select the Private endpoint you want to remove; Select all if you want to delete all.
4. Click on 'Remove'

After this you're good to delete the PLS

[image: This illustrates how you would see it on portal. I've masked sensitive information]

Remember, this doesn't delete he private endpoint. You may still have to ask that organisation to delete it at their end.